# how do i avoid variables conflicts in jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, conflict

i have this function that i used to fetch some pages by jquery ajax that also responsible for active link state of navigation. below is the code that has two same functions that supposed to fetch pages from two different directories and as you seen both functions using same variable name "linkClicked" the problem is that only first function is working and if i removed first function then 2nd function is starting working. what i am trying to say is both functions are not working simultaneously. i know i shouldn't used same variable name twice but changing the variable name to something else also not working!

```
 $(function() {

 $('header nav a').click(function() {
 var $linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
 document.location.hash = $linkClicked;
 var $Top_albumsRoot = $linkClicked.replace('#Top_albums', '');


if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
$("header nav a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load.php",
    data: 'Top_albums='+$Top_albumsRoot,

    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('#main-content').html(msg);
            $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
        }
    }

  });
}
else {
  event.preventDefault();
 }

 });


var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
switch (hash) {
case 'page2' :
  $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
  break;
case 'Top_albums_Pop' :
  $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
  break;
case 'page4' :
  $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
  break;
}
});


$(function() {

$('header nav a').click(function() {
var $linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
document.location.hash = $linkClicked;
var $pageRoot = $linkClicked.replace('#page', '');


if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
$("header nav a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load2.php",
    data: 'page='+$pageRoot,

    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('#main-content').html(msg);
            $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
        }
    }

  });
 }
 else {
  event.preventDefault();
 }

 });

var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
switch (hash) {
case 'page2' :
  $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
  break;
case 'page3' :
  $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
  break;
case 'page4' :
  $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
  break;
}
});
```

these are two php files that linked to these functions respectively load.php and load2.php

```
 <!--load.php-->
 <?php

 if(!$_POST['Top_albums']) die("0");

 $page = (int)$_POST['Top_albums'];

 if(file_exists('Top-albums/Top_albums'.$page.'.html'))
 echo file_get_contents('Top-albums/Top_albums'.$page.'.html');

 else echo 'There is no such page!';
 ?>

<!--load2.php-->
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page'.$page.'.html'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page'.$page.'.html');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

finally this is navigation menu

```
  <li><a href="#page1" class="active" id="page1-link">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page2" id="page2-link">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Top_albums3" id="page3-link">Page3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page4" id="page4-link">Page 4</a></li>
```

so i really need to avoid this conflict to load pages from different directories or if someone have an idea to modify this function to accept different directories at the same time.
p.s: remember first php file suppose to check for pages from "Top-albums" folder and 2nd is from "pages" folder. thanks in advance

Comment: so what is the problem? Use if statement to see if $_POST['page'] or $_POST['Top_albums'] was sent... don't just die("0");

Comment: can you tell me this with code modification because i am new to javascript! please

Comment: if I understood your logic correctly, you send to load.php either $_POST['Top_albums'] or $_POST['page'] and you need to check which one was sent to the page. You use `if(!$_POST['Top_albums']) die("0");` and `if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");` but that is incorrect since die simply stops script execution if first check was wrong so you even do not have a chance to check the second post is true or false.

Comment: or you send different ajax requests on different files? it is not clear from your code why the load2.php code was posted

Comment: yes one to load.php and 2nd to load2.php, the load2.php file is using by 2nd function as you can see in the above thats why i posted and if you understand my problem, right now first function works fine and loads the pages from "Top-albums" folder but the 2nd function didn't! moreover when i remove first function then 2nd function starting working? i mean both functions are not working simultaneously. thanks

Comment: $('header nav a').click in both functions are actually confusing me... you cannot set the 2 different functions on the same action of the jQuery object selected by the same DOM selector...

Comment: what I would suggest:  `<li><a href="#Top_albums3" id="page3-link" class="albums">Page3</a></li>` and `$('header nav .albums').click` and class="pages" and selector `$('header nav .pages').click` for pages links

Comment: sorry but i tried it and this is also not working! is there any way to modify first function to load pages from different directories as i wish and get rid of 2nd function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<header>
 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#page1" class="active" id="page1-link">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2" id="page2-link">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Top_albums3" id="page3-link">Page3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page4" id="page4-link">Page 4</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
 $('header nav a').on('click', function() {
     var linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
     if(linkClicked.indexOf('page') == true)
     {
         var $pageRoot = linkClicked.replace('#page', '');
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load2.php",
            data: 'page='+$pageRoot,

            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg){

                if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                {
                    $('#main-content').html(msg);
                    $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
                }
            }

          });
     }
     else
     {
       var $Top_albumsRoot = linkClicked.replace('#Top_albums', '');        
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "load.php",
                data: 'Top_albums='+$Top_albumsRoot,

                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg){

                    if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                    {
                        $('#main-content').html(msg);
                        $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
                    }
                }            
              });
     }
 });

});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/5uotecym/1/

Comment: first of all thnks you very very very much. it works but what if i have more directories this works with two 1(pages) 2(Top-albums) as you can seen on above php files. how to further modified it so it supports atleast 5 directories? thanks again................waiting for your kind ans.